# How to select column2 but if column2 is zero than select column1

Tags: mysql, sql, select, woocommerce, case

I have the following woocommerce table (wp_wc_order_product_lookup):

```
|---------------------|-------------------|
|      product_id     |     variant_id    |
|---------------------|-------------------|
|          23         |         0         |
|          24         |         32        |
|          25         |         34        |
|---------------------|-------------------|
```

I would like to make a mysql query which gives me the product_id. If the variant_id is 0 than return the product_id else I would like to get the variant_id:

```
|---------------------|
|      product_id     | 
|---------------------|
|          23         |
|          32         |
|          34         |
|---------------------|
```

Comment: Note that if '0' was NULL, this could be done very simply with COALESCE

Comment: Yes i try that but doesnot work because its zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `case` expression:

```
select case when variant_id = 0 then product_id else variant_id end as product_id
from mytable
```

Comment: I dont know why but i got this error: Unknown column 'variant_id' in 'field list' . I try to use quote but still does not work.

Comment: @ZsoltJanes: well, your sample data shows a column by that name. What is the actual name of the column then?

Comment: My bad it was variation_id. Thanks